# Rails 4.2+: deep nesting resources when it's required to display data from entire resource chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, nested-resources

I'm familiar with the guideline not to nest more than 1 level deep, and I understand the various discussions about having the shortest URLs possible both in and out of code.

Most of the StackOverflow questions and Googling I've done answer this by presenting use cases where one doesn't have to access all elements in the entire chain.

But what do you do when you have to access the parent resources further up the chain for every page you're working with?

`/{ACCOUNT_SLUG}/applications/{APPLICATION_UUID}/borrower/employments/{UUID}`

When dealing with a single `employment` record, I have to display account-specific information take from the parent `account` object via the `ACCOUNT_SLUG`, as well as `application` information. And technically, my `borrower` is also a DB query, but since there is only 1 for each application, I don't have to add an id/slug in the URL.

General advice is to do something like:

`/employments/{UUID}`

But if I do that, then in my controller code (and elsewhere) I still have to do:

```
@employment = Employment.find_by(uuid: params[:uuid])
@account = @employment.borrower.application.account
```

So I have to walk the entire parent association chain and execute those association DB queries. How does one resolve this kind of situation where the deep nested association has to be kept, from the first parent to the last child?

**1: Add association attributes to all the children**

```
class Employment
  belongs_to :borrower
  belongs_to :application
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Now I've got a bunch of associations going on everywhere, just to walk a clear chain. This seems like "dependency hell" to me?...

**2: Go with deep nested routes; Github does it**

I've noticed Github actually employs deep nested routes:

`github.com/{USERNAME}/{REPO}/settings/hooks`

While not as deeply-nested as my use case, they still nest everything underneath the `username` and `repo`, and if you list out their verbose URL it is:

`/github.com/accounts/{USERNAME}/repos/{REPO_NAME}/settings/hooks`

Is anyone aware if Github has a method of optimizing this deep nesting, or are they just looking up the `account` and `repo` with every request and biting the DB query overhead (probably not that big a deal...)?

**3: Deep nest the routes, but make your own URL helpers to keep it clean**

Using `/{ACOUNT_SLUG}/applications/{APPLICATION_UUID}/borrower/employments/{UUID}`, the URL helper would look something like:

```
account_applications_borrower_employments_path(@account, @application, @borrower, @employment)
```

This could be cleaned up using some helpers:

```
def borrower_employment_path(@employment)
  @borrower = @employment.borrower
  @application = @borrower.application
  @account = @application.account
  account_applications_borrower_employments_path(@account, @application, @borrower, @employment)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Very detailed question. Kinda late to respond, but in the past when the problem of nested resources has bitten me, it usually ends up that I need to revisit the way I relationally modeled my database.

Of the possible solutions you suggested, number 1 is probably the best considering the opinionated nature of the Rails framework. Rails associations are very powerful and leveraging them is useful as your app scales.

Addressing concerns about dependencies between your models:

Without seeing your schema, I can only guess, but your modeling could look like this:

```
Class Account
  has_many :applications
end

Class Application
  belongs_to :account
  has_one :borrower
  has_one :employment
end

Class Borrower
  belongs_to :application
end

Class Employment
  belongs_to :application
  has_one :account, through: :application
end
```

This is my best guess from the dissecting the info above.  With this modeling, you would be able to do this in a controller action:

```
def action_name
  @employment = Employment.find_by(uuid: params[:uuid])
  @account = @employment.account
end
```

You would be able to add extra associations, say, if you wanted to do:
    @employment.borrower

by adding:

```
class Employment
  belongs_to :application
  has_one :account, through: :application
  has_one :borrower, through: :application
end
```

I always give this a good read every once and while just to keep it fresh:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations

Rails has generally discouraged heavily nested routing, despite Github's implementation of their application:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources